# How to upload a file to S3 and make it public using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am able to upload an image file using:

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)
bucket.upload_file(file, key)
```

However, I want to make the file public too. I tried looking up for some functions to set ACL for the file but seems like boto3 have changes their API and removed some functions. Is there a way to do it in the latest release of boto3?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I was able to do it using objectAcl API:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('bucket_name','object_key')
response = object_acl.put(ACL='public-read')
```

For details: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectacl

Comment: One liner if you're only updating one object
`boto3.resource('s3').ObjectAcl('bucket_name','object_key').put(ACL='public-read')`

Comment: This works as well as `ACL = 'public-read'`: `GrantRead   = 'uri="http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"'`

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, apparently public-read is the **default**, for now. See the giant warning in https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Answer (score 147):

To upload and set permission to publicly-readable in one step, you can use:

`bucket.upload_file(file, key, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})`

See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html#the-extraargs-parameter

Comment: Doesn't work with boto3, anyway:
`botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "ExtraArgs", must be one of: ACL, Body, Bucket, CacheControl, ContentDisposition, ContentEncoding, ContentLanguage, ContentLength, ContentMD5, ContentType, Expires, GrantFullControl, GrantRead, GrantReadACP, GrantWriteACP, Key, Metadata, ServerSideEncryption, StorageClass, WebsiteRedirectLocation, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, SSEKMSKeyId, RequestPayer, Tagging, ObjectLockMode, ObjectLockRetainUntilDate, ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus`

Comment: Worked for me with boto3

Comment: Works with boto3 and Object.
`Object(bucket, key).upload_file(path, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43023965/3191896

Answer (score 13):

[Adi's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909293/1939344) works. However, if you were like me, you might have run into an access denied issue. This is normally caused by broken permissions of the user. 
I fixed it by adding the following to the `Action` array:

```
"s3:GetObjectAcl",
"s3:PutObjectAcl"
```

Comment: Where do you declare the Action array?

Comment: @Rohan, could you explain in more detail what this `Action` array is?

Comment: Wrote this a long time ago and missed the comments.
Sorry for the confusion. Check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_action.html

Answer (score 0):

In the recent versions of boto, `ACL` is available as a regular parameter - both when using the S3 client and resource, it seems. You can just specify `ACL="public_read"` without having to wrap it with `ExtraParams` or using `ObjectAcl` API.

Comment: It must be `public-read` and not `public_read`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ACL="public-read"` as mentioned above.

Also, make sure your bucket policy `Resource` line
has both the bare arn and `/*` arn formats.
Not having them both can cause strange permissions problems.

```
...
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*", "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"]
```